# Adding a varchar to a datetime column and dealing with nulls

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns in my table a `varchar(8)` titled `Trans_Time` which holds data in an `XX:XX:XX` time format and a `DateTime` column named `Trand_Date` which holds just a the date component in `XX-XX-XXXX` format.

I am trying to combine the two columns to get a full date and time (i.e. if `Trans_Time` is `08:10:14` and `Trand_Date` is `04-04-2007` the output should be `04-04-2007 08:10:14`).

My problem is that some times the `Trans_Time` is null and this produces an output of null.

Is there some way I can treat null as `00:00:00`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ISNULL or COALESCE in T-SQL to replace a null value:

```
SELECT 
  Trand_Date + ' ' + COALESCE(Trans_Time, '00:00:00') AS Trand_DateTime1,
  Trand_Date + ' ' + ISNULL(Trans_Time, '00:00:00') AS Trand_DateTime2
FROM MyTable
```

Both columns above should return the same value. Note that if you want to perform date-based comparisons, e.g. `DATEDIFF`, `DATEADD` or even something as simple as `WHERE Trand_DateTime < GETDATE()`, you can create a view of the table that presents the values as an actual SQL DateTime datatype like so:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewTransDateTimes]
AS
SELECT 
  CAST(Trand_Date + 'T' + COALESCE(Trans_Time, '00:00:00') as DateTime) AS Trand_DateTime
  --, [OTHER COLUMNS]
FROM MyTable
GO
```

Then you can do things like:

```
SELECT * FROM ViewTransDateTimes
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, Trand_DateTime, GETDATE()) < 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using isnull to replace the null value.

```
select isnull(null, '00:00:00')
```